# Image not seen in PDF when inserted from alfresco repository

Tags: html, pdf, alfresco, alfresco-share

when I insert an image in HTML and convert it to PDF through a rule, the image is not seen in the PDF. Strangely, if the image is on some remote server except alfresco repository, it can be seen. So, it has problem only with showing Alfresco repository images. 
Please suggest as how this problem can be dealt with?
I tried guest=true parameter in my URL, but that doesn't solve the problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this will not work with the existing implementation of Alfresco because the standard transform mechanism will copy the file to the tomcat temp dir outside Alfresco to convert it from there. That implementation can only handle single files and is not able to parse/embed relative paths to the Alfresco repository. For this to work you need a parser/resolver in a (not yet existing) transformer which knows how to get the context of the file and how to resove urls.

I think the easiest way to get this done is to write/register a new transformer which provides the webdav url (and nodeRef) as parameters and to write a simple shell script which converts the html using webdav url and admin credentials. To do it the *right* way would be much more work ...

If anybody knows an existing transformer which is able to run in repository context: please rise hands!

Comment: Such a feature would be very suspicious regarding security. The content of node A would be embedded into a rendition of node B.
But node A has it own ACL they may change. So a user might be allowed to read node B but not allowed to read node A.

Comment: Thanks Heiko for replying. Can you please provide an example of how that can be done? If converting to PDF is a problem, is there any other way I can convert it to a printable document through JavaScript?